# Is there a better way to construct a controller with multiple parameters the might not be required?

Tags: spring-boot, controller, http-request-parameters

I'm making a simple spring boot application and i have to get a list of objects, which i filter by parameters that aren't required. So basically the user can send the parameters, but doesn't have to. Best solution that i found is the use of @RequestParam annotation but it doesn't seem to work. If i put both parameters it works perfectly but if I set just one or none i get an error. Do i have to overload methods for every case or is there a smoother way to deal with this(if possible by still using the get request)?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(
                value = "/fruits",
                params = {"apple", "orange"},
                method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Fruit>> getFruits(
@RequestParam(value = "apple", required = false, defaultValue = "") 
List<Apple> apple,
@RequestParam(value ="orange", required = false, defaultValue = "") 
List<Orange> orange) {

List<Fruit> fruit = projectService.getFruits(apple, orange);
  return ResponseEntity.ok().body(fruit);
}
```

Error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-01-20T21:26:52.287+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Parameter conditions \"apple, orange\" not met for actual 
request parameters: ",
"path": "/api/fruits"
}
```

Comment: Remove this line  params ={"apple","orange"} and it will work.

Comment: @JonathanJohx THAT WAS IT! Good lord i was having so much trouble trying to figure that one out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
 params ={"apple","orange"}
```

and it will work. 
Because you don't need to call twice, it's enough with those @RequestParam annotations.